# `ModuleNotFoundError`: How to organize a python module work as CLI and a library

Tags: python

Yet another python ModuleNotFoundError question:

I want to build a python script that can be both use as a CLI tool and a library.

My tool structure looks like this

```
mytool
├── dep
│   └── util.py # Contains my_utility_function()
└── tool.py
```

When using it as library (as a git submodule), I expect to be able to use it in the following way:

```
.
├── main.py              # from libraries.mytool import tool
└── libraries
    └── mytool
        ├── dep
        │   └── util.py  # Contains my_utility_function()
        └── tool.py      # from dep.util import upper_case
```

When using the CLI tool directly `python tool.py` works great.

The problem when trying to use `python main.py`; I get

```
  from dep.util import my_utility_function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dep'
```

As you can guess the problem is from the import in `tool.py`:

```py
from dep.util import my_utility_function
# ...
```

The only way I found to fix this problem is to do this hack in `tool.py`:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from dep.util import my_utility_function
else:
    from .dep.util import my_utility_function
#        ^
#        note this dot
```

Is there a cleaner way to handle this problem?
Thanks, your help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe something from importlib? https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly may be useful? alternatively, tool.py could add its path to sys.path and then try the import?